# Issue in synchronization contacts from multiple websites

Tags: tridion, tridion2009, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are facing problem with profilesync service of audience manager.

We have the scenario, where we are doing subscription in 2 steps:

1. We are taking user email address which is unique id and we save the record in tridion_submgmt and later profile sync service saved this record to tridion_email DB with this unique email id.
2. We are taking user date of birth and mobile no and we want to update the same record.

These 2 steps are run one after other.

Also we have 87 websites where we have different address book and one single synchronization target settings.

We are facing problem with synchronization, sometime record is updating but sometime record is not updating by step 2.

any suggestion please?

Comment: Why are you running these two steps separately? Do you want them to opt-in first and later add their day of birth? Otherwise it seems that @Gertjan-Assies his answer is correct, right?

Answer (score 9):

Are you directly adding the records to the database? This is not supported and can interfer with the proper working of the syncing process.

If you use the API to update the record (on the Content Manager or on the Content Delivery side) it will automatically trigger the sync service and makes sure the information is synced correctly

A small (java) example based on your requirements:

```
Contact testContact = new Contact();
testContact.setExtendedDetail("Email", "user@domain.com");
testContact.setExtendedDetail("MobileNr", "1234567890");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(1970, Calendar.OCTOBER, 17, 0, 0, 0); // 17 okt 1970   
testContact.getDetails().get("dateOfBirth").setFieldValue(calendar.getTime());

testContact.save();
```

Comment: We are exactly using the same API code that you are suggesting. But still the problem is that record is getting updated some time But some it's not.

Comment: Then I need some more information, could you share some of the code, and explain your setup in more detail

Comment: Are these problems happening in certain addressbooks? Maybe it is somewhere an incorrect addressbookID?

Comment: For the first time when we capture email it get updated, but for the second time it some times reflects and sometimes not. So it is not issue of incorrect AddressBookId.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, we have to set the contact AddressBookId in order to sync to specific address book.

testContact.setGroupId(20); // 20 is the address book id

This is java sample code. for .net I believe it is testContact.AddressBookId = 20 .